# C++ primer 5 edition: shared_ptr initialized from uniqe_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

On C++ primer 5  edition. Chapter 12. Dynamic memory: It is written:

> shared_ptr p(u); P assumes ownership from the `uniqe_ptr` `u`; makes `u` null.
>   shared_ptr p(q, d) Assumes ownership for the object to which the built-in pointer `q` points. `q` must be convertible to `T*` ($4.11.2, p.161).
>   `p` will use the callable object `d` ($10.3.2, p.388) in place of `delete` to free `q`.

- I didn't understand "Assumes ownership from the `unque_ptr` and for the object to which the built-in...".

Can someone explain to me this paragraph? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is not clear with types. you need an rvalue ref to [construct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) a `shared_ptr` from `unique_ptr`:

> ```
> template< class Y, class Deleter >
> shared_ptr( std::unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&& r );
> ```

check this code:

```
unique_ptr<int> up{new int{10}};
shared_ptr<int> sp(move(up));
cout << *sp <<'\n';
//cout << *up <<'\n'; // up is nullptr
```

Live ob [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jv0Fiy)

---

smart pointers manage the lifetime of raw pointer they own. `unique_ptr` doesn't share ownership while `shared_ptr` does. When you construct a `shared_ptr` from a `unique_ptr` you have to give up its ownership via move, and `unique_ptr` cannot be copied.

I think by using "assumes ownership" the author wants to state that, bad things can still happen if you somehow modify the pointer owned by smart pointers.

Comment: Because passing an `l-value` of `unque_ptr` to the constructor of `shared_ptr` will generate an error.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa exactly. because you cannot copy a unique_ptr

Comment: Or I can do: `std::shared_ptr<int> spi(std::make_unique<int>(10))` directly. Because `make_unique` as an argument to `shared_ptr` ctor will create a r-value `unique_ptr` is it correct?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa yes, it is an rvalue reference(unnamed temporary). In my example I create the rvalue reference using move :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa No problem. enjoy the glorious smart pointers :)

Comment: Yea for sure!. thanks to you all the good members always save my day, Because I always want to understand to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers 'own' (or, perhaps better, 'manage') an underlying raw pointer or object.

`unique_ptr` owns the pointer outright and will delete it when it goes out of scope.  `shared_ptr` potentially shares ownership with other `shared_ptr`s, and the managed object will be deleted when the last `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

So, in your example, the newly created `shared_ptr` takes over ownership from the `unique_ptr`, leaving the latter owning nothing.

Comment: So is there a `shared_ptr` constructor that can take a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr, item 13.